# How to set an environment variable in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (Python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been working on a Django application lately, trying to get it to work with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

In my `.ebextensions/python.config` file, I have set the following:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name:  ProductionBucket
    value: s3-bucket-name
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name:  ProductionCache
    value:  memcached-server.site.com:11211
```

However, whenever I look on the server, no such environment variables are set (and as such, aren't accessible when I try `os.getenv('ProductionBucket')`

I came across this [this page](https://gist.github.com/808968) which appears to attempt to document all the namespaces. I've also tried using `PARAM1` as the option name, but have had similar results.

How can I set environment variables in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

**EDIT**:
I have also tried adding a command prior to all other commands which would just export an environment variable:

```
commands:
 01_env_vars:
  command: "source scripts/env_vars"
```

... This was also unsuccessful

Comment: Maybe the PARAM1 etc ones are used for this? Seems like a big limitation though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-php

Comment: This might help too - http://grigory.ca/2012/09/getting-started-with-django-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk/

Comment: Have you tried using `aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:varname`?

Comment: I have tried those methods and have likewise been unsuccessful :S

Comment: I'll have a try later this week when I'm working on AWS EB, will let you know how I go.

Comment: I am having the same problem on a Ruby on Rails platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked using a modern (i.e., non legacy) container, and found it under /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration as a json file.

The Behaviour seems to be Platform-Dependent: I remember in PHP in particular, it also creates some shell scripts with the values.

Regardless of that, look into /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy.

Java case again, it runs this python script, which looks quite handy for you:

https://gist.github.com/19c1e4b718f9a70a4ce1

Comment: While that certainly sheds some light as to how the environment variables are set, I was hoping that there might be some information regarding doing this through the configuration files.

Comment: Look into the ```/hooks/configdeploy``` folder contents. This file is ran whenever you set the environment settings - including the configuration. You must log and look into your python-based environment, as its a different beast

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same problem.

Believe it or not, you have to commit the `.ebextensions` directory and all `*.config` files to version control before you deploy in order for them to show up as environment variables on the server.

In order to keep sensitive information out of version control, you can use a config file like this:

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: API_LOGIN
    value: placeholder
  - option_name: TRANS_KEY
    value: placeholder
  - option_name: PROVIDER_ID
    value: placeholder
```

Then edit the configuration in the AWS admin panel (Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties) and update the values there.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14491294/274695) helpful.

Comment: @idrinkpabst afaik, .ebextensions can be ignored by version control (it prob should in case you have some sensitive info in any config file) when you deploy if you use an .ebignore file. see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=621059#621059

Answer (score 6):

**Option 1:**

You can set environment variables using `eb setenv FOO=bar`

You can view the environment variables using `eb printenv`

**Option 2:**

You can create a config file in your .ebextensions directory, for example `00_environment.config`. Then, add your environment variables like this:

`option_settings:
  - option_name: MY_FIRST_ENV_VAR
    value: abc
  - option_name: ANOTHER_ENV_VAR
    value: 123`

However, if you have multiple environments, I have found that it is more useful to set the environment variables directly, using option #1.

I also have found the `eb config` commands to be helpful: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-config.html

These commands allow you to get, put, list, or delete configuration files on your eb environment.

The command `eb config get` will save your config, including environment variables, to a local file in `.elasticbeanstalk/saved_configs`.

Comment: How does eb deploy know to use 00_environment.config and not 01_environment.config?

Comment: @Learner it loads all `.ebextensions/*.config` files in alphabetical order. See [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html#configuration-options-precedence): `Configuration files are executed in alphabetical order. For example, .ebextensions/01run.config is executed before .ebextensions/02do.config.`

Answer (score 5):

I did the following to also get my environment variables that I configure in cloudformation in the non-container phase, eg the regular commands

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | python -c "import json,sys; obj=json.load(sys.stdin); f = open('/tmp/eb_env', 'w'); f.write('\n'.join(map(lambda x: 'export ' + x[0] + '=' + x[1], obj.iteritems())))"
```

Once you execute this command you will have a file in /tmp/eb_env with all your environment variables. Just execute the following before a command that needs the environment variables

```
source /tmp/eb_env
```

Example

```
source /tmp/eb_env && echo $MY_CUSTOM_ENV
```

In the config file of elastic beanstalk, it looks like this:

```
commands:
    02-make-sure-we-can-get-our-env-in-the-instance-itself:
        command: "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment | python -c 'import json,sys; obj=json.load(sys.stdin); f = open(\'/tmp/eb_env\', \'w\'); f.write(\'\n\'.join(map(lambda x: \'export \' + x[0] + \'=\' + x[1], obj.iteritems())))'"
```

Answer (score 1):

To set variables on a local run, you can do the following:

```
eb local setenv CONFIG=dev
eb local run
```

This also works with Docker MultiContainers, which otherwise will not see your environment.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for those who still have the same question like I did here is the solution from AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-softwaresettings.html

> To configure environment properties in the Elastic Beanstalk console
>
> 1. Open the [Elastic Beanstalk console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk), and then, in the regions drop-down
>      list, select your region.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose **Environments**, and then choose your
>      environment's name on the list.
> 3. In the navigation pane, choose **Configuration**.
> 4. In the **Software** configuration category, choose Edit.
> 5. Under **Environment properties**, enter key-value pairs.
> 6. Choose **Apply**.