# how to make .ebextensions work when deploying a node js application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having troubles understanding how `.ebextensions` is used when deploying a node js application using  elasticbeanstalk. I have created a file called `01run.config` in the top directory of may application:

```
my_app:
   |-- server.js
   |-- site/(...)
   |-- node-modules
   |-- .ebextensions/01run.config
```

The file .ebextensions contains my AWS credentials and a parameter referring to a S3 bundle that my app uses.

```
option_settings:
  - option_name: AWS_SECRET_KEY
    value:  MY-AWS-SECRET-KEY
  - option_name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    value: MY-AWS-KEY-ID
  - option_name: PARAM1
    value: MY-S3-BUNDLE-ID
```

After deploying my app using `eb create`, an `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.my_app-env` is created that contains many variables, amongst which `PARAM1` is set to "". Also the credentials do not exist.
I think I read somewhere that `.ebextensions` is when initiating the application, so this is not necessarily bad that I don't see these variables in the optionsettings.my_app-env'. However, the variables are not set up, and the application does not work properly. I'd appreciate any explanations.
I find that official documentation a bit confusing to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that I had not commited `.ebextensions` to git. Apparently, the file is read on initializing your application, so it has to be part of the bundle sent to elasticbeanstalk.

I had taken the idea of using the config file to set up the authentication keys from the amazon documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_custom_container.html.
However, I had not commited the file because it is clear that you are not supposed to commit your authentication keys (more on this discussion here: [How do you pass custom environment variable on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (AWS EBS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-custom-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-aws-ebs)).

I end up simplifying the file to contain the PARAM1 option, and I passed the secret key and access key id throughout the elasticbenastalk online interface.

Comment: Amazon has terrible half-assed documentation!

Answer (score 0):

Your config file example is missing the namespace. You must specify namespace for each of your option settings.

Comment: that's not quite right. the default namespace is   aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the environment options in the `.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.[your-env-name]` file.

You should have a section called `[aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment]`.  It might be populated with `PARAM1=`...etc.  Just add your environment variables under this section.  The files in the `.elasticbeanstalk` directory should not be committed.

After doing `eb update` you can verify that the options were added if you go to the web-based EBS console.  The new options should show up.  I *believe* that any old options added through the console do not get removed.