# What is the best practices for storing connections string when deploying c# webapi into aws beanstalk?

Tags: c#, connection-string, configuration-files, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am writing a small webapi in c#, that using mongodb as the storage, and I am wondering where to store the connection string. I know I can use the webconfig, and change between configuration per debug and release. But, I found this [link](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx1XG3FX6VMU6O5/A-safer-way-to-distribute-AWS-credentials-to-EC2) that show how to load java properties file from a s3 bucket.

So I am wondering if it also possible when using beanstalk, and if so - does this is the best practices? This is the first time I am deploying something to aws, until now I used azure, where you can use the cscfg file for that purpose.

Thanks, 
Omer

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the question was not answered. I think that the proper way to achieve seems to be using environment variable, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-custom-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-aws-ebs) for example. If you had any better idea, I would like to hear.

Comment: I found two alternative: a) store the connection strings in s3 and allow only the role associated with the ec2 access it. b) encrypt the web.config using Aspnet_regiis.exe. I solved it in azure by storing all sensitive data as secrets in the KeyVault which is also a nice solution.