# Is the name of an Elastic Beanstalk environment available as an environment property?

Tags: amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Knowing how to set custom environment variables on AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I wonder if there is a default environment property for the name of the environment. If there is, where is this described in the documentation?

For example, suppose my EB environment is named "my_env," is there some kind of default environment property like e.g. "AWS_EB_ENV_NAME" that I can access to obtain this name?

Comment: Based on the answer by Tom Paulus, the simplest approach is still to set an environment property with the following value `\`{ "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" }\``, either using the EB management console, or using `option_settings: ...` in an `.ebextensions` config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set the environment variable yourself during the instance creation via an [ebextension](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options) or the Web Console during environment creation. Described here: [How do you pass custom environment variable on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (AWS EBS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211007/how-do-you-pass-custom-environment-variable-on-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-aws-ebs)

Or you can use a combination of requests to the Meta-Data server, which sits between your EC2 instance and the netwrok, and the AWS EB API; as described in: https://serverfault.com/questions/630075/is-it-possible-to-get-metadata-about-the-elastic-beanstalk-environment-from-the

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is "No?"

Comment: Did you read the second link that @Tom-Paulus provided? It is completely possible to do what you want with a combination of `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`, `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environments`, and `aws elasticbeanstalk describe-environment-resources`.

Comment: @Brian, yes I did read the second link, and I completely understand that it is completely possible using that approach. However, my question was whether there exists a default environment variable for this purpose. It seems there does not.

Comment: It'd be much simpler to set an environment variable in an ebextension with the output of this command:
`/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k environment_name`